# Cassandra: update or insert map value together with other values

Tags: cassandra

I have a table that looks like this:

```
(id, a, b, mapValue)
```

I want to update if exist or insert if not `VALUES(id,a,b,mapValue)`. Where mapValue is the combination of the old mapValue with the new one, replacing the values of each key that was already there.

For example if the old mapValue was `{1:c, 2:d}` and the new one is `{2:e, 3:f}` the result would be `{1:c, 2:e, 3:f}`.
I want to do this in a query that also updates/inserts `id,a,b` in `VALUES(id,a,b,mapValue)`.

How can I achieve this?
I've found [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useInsertMap.html) guide about updating maps but it doesn't say anything about updating them while dealing with other values in the table. I need to do this at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra, there is no difference between INSERT & UPDATE - everything is UPSERT, so when you do `UPDATE` and data doesn't exist, it's inserted. Or if you do `INSERT` and data already exist, it will be updated.

Regarding map update, you can use `+` and `-` operations on the corresponding column when doing `UPDATE`. For example, I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.m1 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    i int,
    m map<int, text>
);
```

and I can do following to update existing row:

```
cqlsh:test> insert into test.m1 (id, i, m) values (1, 1, {1:'t1'});
cqlsh:test> select * from test.m1;

 id | i | m
----+---+-----------
  1 | 1 | {1: 't1'}

(1 rows)

cqlsh:test> update test.m1 set m = m + {2:'t2'}, i = 4 where id = 1;
cqlsh:test> select * from test.m1;

 id | i | m
----+---+--------------------
  1 | 4 | {1: 't1', 2: 't2'}

(1 rows)
```

and I can use the similar `UPDATE` command to insert completely new data:

```
cqlsh:test> update test.m1 set m = m + {6:'t6'}, i = 6 where id = 6;
cqlsh:test> select * from test.m1;

 id | i | m
----+---+--------------------
  1 | 4 | {1: 't1', 2: 't2'}
  6 | 6 |          {6: 't6'}

(2 rows)
```

Usually, if you know that no data existed before for given primary key, then `UPDATE` with `+` is better way to insert data into `set` or `map` because it doesn't generate a tombstone that is generated when you do `INSERT` or `UPDATE` without `+` on the collection column.

P.S. You can find more information on using collections in the [following document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/dataModel.html).